# error: expecting property name or receiver type - Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Not able to figure out what is wrong with below code and why I am getting below error :

```
/**
 * Example:
 * var ti = TreeNode(5)
 * var v = ti.`val`
 * Definition for a binary tree node.
 * class TreeNode(var `val`: Int) {
 *     var left: TreeNode? = null
 *     var right: TreeNode? = null
 * }
 */
class Solution {
    fun pathSum(root: TreeNode?, sum: Int): List<List<Int>> {
        var result : List<MutableList<Int>> = listOf(mutableListOf())
        var path : MutableList<Int> = mutableListOf()
        dfs(root, sum, result, path)
        return result
    }

    fun dfs(root: TreeNode?, sum: Int, result: List<MutableList<Int>>, path: MutableList<Int>){

        if(root == null) return

        path.add(sum)

        dfs(root.left, sum - root.val, result, path)
        dfs(root.right, sum - root.val, result, path)

        if(sum == 0 &&
                root.left == null &&
                root.right == null) {           
            result.add(path)
        }

        path.remove(path.size() - 1)

    }
}
```

I am getting below lots of compile time errors while running above code, new to Kotlin struggling to figure out root cause :

```
Line 24: Char 38: error: expecting property name or receiver type
            dfs(root.left, sum - root.val, result, path)
                                         ^
    Line 24: Char 46: error: expecting an element
            dfs(root.left, sum - root.val, result, path)
```

Comment: I don't think it is a good idea to use language keywords as names for class attributes. The Kotlin Playground doesn't like that already... Call it `value` but not `val` in `TreeNode`...

Comment: `val` is a keyword for non-mutable property in Kotlin. You can name properties/functions this way using `\`val\``, and calling them by `root.\`val\`` but anyway it is a bad practice

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out guys. BTW I am solving problems on Leetcode and they have built -in TreeNode defined which has val property. Infact they have already pointed out to use `val` which I did not pay attention.

Answer (score 0):

`val` is a keyword in kotlin. If you want to use it as a name of a field,
you need to wrap it into backticks: `val`
(actually, the code example in the comment before your code shows that).